# while executing below code it showing error

Tags: plsql, cursor, rowtype

This is my pl/sql program:

```
 declare
   m_no      emp.emp_no%rowtype;
   m_name    emp.emp_name%rowtype;
   m_address emp.address%rowtype;
   cursor raju is 
     SELECT emp_no,
            emp_name,
            address 
       from emp;
 begin
   open raju;
   loop
     fetch raju 
      into m_no,
           m_name,
           m_address;
     dbms_output.put_line(m_no ||''||m_name||''||m_address);
     EXIT WHEN raju%notfound;
   end loop;
   close raju;
 end;
```

while executing above code am getting error

> Error report:
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 6:
>   PLS-00310: with %ROWTYPE attribute, 'EMP.EMP_NO' must name a table, cursor or cursor-variable
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 6:
>   PL/SQL: Item ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 3, column 8:
>   PLS-00310: with %ROWTYPE attribute, 'EMP.EMP_NAME' must name a table, cursor or cursor-variable
>   ORA-06550: line 3, column 8:
>   PL/SQL: Item ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 4, column 11:
>   PLS-00310: with %ROWTYPE attribute, 'EMP.ADDRESS' must name a table, cursor or cursor-variable
>   ORA-06550: line 4, column 11:
>   PL/SQL: Item ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 10, column 18:
>   PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
>   ORA-06550: line 10, column 2:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 11, column 23:
>   PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
>   ORA-06550: line 11, column 2:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

but I didn't get where it showing and where it error occurring. Any one suggest me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable declaration is wrong.

Since you are selecting and storing the columns separately, you should declare it using [%TYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/type_attribute.htm#i36397) attribute.

```
m_no      emp.emp_no%type;
m_name    emp.emp_name%type;
m_address emp.address%type
```

[%ROWTYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/rowtype_attribute.htm#LNPLS01342) attribute is used if you are using single variable to store all columns.

```
m_emp emp%rowtype
```